# How to wrap content in the div?

Tags: html, css

i have flexbox container and divs in it. I want the content to stay inside the div. In the sense that if the content exceeds the width of div then it should start from next line.

What i have tried doing?
used white-space: nowrap property. This added horizontal scrollbar which is not desired.

Below is the code,

CSS:

```
.notification_message_wrapper { 
    width: calc(100% - 450px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    left: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

.box {
     background-color: white;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     top: 100px;
     left: 250px;
     flex: 1;
 }

.message {
    display: flex;
    color: green;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;

.content {
    height: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}}}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="box_wrapper">
        <div class="box">
             <div class='message>
                <div class="container">
                    <div>title</div>
                    <div>detail</div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Debug</h2>
                            someresponse
                        <div/></div></div></div></div>
                    <div>close</div></div>
```

The divs with title, detail should not go out of the div...how could i solve this. could someone help. thanks.

Comment: One major syntactical error, you're missing a closing quote in this line: <div class='message>

Answer (score 0):

just add `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden` to your div.  refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Comment: What if we want that content to be straight-up visible and not scrollable? What should be changed in the case? @deeva